# Adding text and textbox values to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I am trying to add text and textbox/combobox values to a cell. I am not sure what the proper context to type in to display this is. I keep getting an error, but I am not sure if it is because I a have too many quotations or because I am not calling things out properly. My current code is shown below.

```
Range("E1")= "UPDATE NOTE TO SAY SEX: "&ComboBox1.Value&",NAME: "&TextBox2.Value&", AGE: " &TextBox3.Value
```

Comment: This is really silly, but try adding some spaces between your quotes and &.  `... SAY SEX: " & ComboBox1.Value & ", NAME: ...`

Comment: @BruceWayne is right, excel's VBE is not very smart and has a hard time adding in the spaces when necessary sometimes. In order for the code to compile and run this properly, you need spaces for it to recognize the variables.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
Range("E1").Value = "UPDATE NOTE TO SAY SEX: " & ComboBox1.Value & _ 
  ", NAME: " & TextBox2.Text & _
  ", AGE: " & TextBox3.Text
```